# Can we implement multiple Content Providers to WhatsApp stickers app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, whatsapp-stickers

As my requirements are my app has the functionality of creating **Custom Stickers and Stickers From Server** a Single Content Provider causing issues, I tried a lot adding multiple Content Providers it's causing issues in **Edit configuration**
As seen below
[image]

- This is how I am trying to add providers in manifest

  ```
       <provider
       android:name=".whats_app_based_code.provider.StickerContentProvider"
       android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true"
       android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ">
   </provider>
   <provider
       android:name=".whats_app_based_code.provider.StickerContentProviderServer"
       android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true"
       android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ">
   </provider>
  ```
- App Level Gradle

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.numan.stickersapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".WhatsAppLicensedCode.StickerContentProvider"
    def contentProviderAuthority2 =applicationId+".WhatsAppLicensedCode.StickerContentProviderServer"
    // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
    manifestPlaceholders = [contentProviderAuthority: "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\""]
    manifestPlaceholders = [contentProviderAuthorityserver: "\"${contentProviderAuthority2}\""]
    // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
    buildConfigField("String", "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY", "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
    buildConfigField("String","CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY_SERVER","\"${contentProviderAuthority2}\"")
    buildConfigField 'String', 'STICKERS_BASE_URL', "\"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/\""


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can i get Whatsapp providers links?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did this part I am adding my approach to achieve this because Someone like me may want to add such functionality to their app:
What I actually did is:

- I only added a single content provider in **App Level Gradle** and removed the other one
- I added the second content provider through manifest and hardcoded the complete provider package like this:

  ```
       <provider
       android:name=".whats_app_based_code.provider.StickerContentProvider"
       android:authorities="${contentProviderAuthority}"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true"
       android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ">
   </provider>
   <provider
       android:name=".whats_app_based_code.provider.StickerContentProviderServer"
       android:authorities="com.numan.stickersapp.whats_app_based_code.provider.WhatsAppLicensedCode.StickerContentProviderServer"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:exported="true"
       android:readPermission="com.whatsapp.sticker.READ">
   </provider>
  ```